# Find duplicate account and contact records when converting via Apex

Tags: apex, leads, lead-conversion, duplicate-management

I am converting leads through a HttpPost method and using the Database.LeadConvert class for conversion. After conversion I am working the opportunity and not with the contact or the account; however, contact and account are not optional when converting a lead so for every conversion I am stuck with a random contact and account record getting created. Each lead is going to be unique so each account and contact will also be unique and the lead cannot be merged with existing account or contact. The standard account/contact duplicate rule are in place if the Sales rep need to convert the lead manually.

How should handle this extra record creation?

Without breaking the flow, how should I handle duplicate account/contact if created after conversion?

Comment: Not entirely sure what your question is. Since leads are unique, you are saying Account/ Contact will also be unique. So not entirely sure about your concern for duplicates. Can you explain

Comment: @AshwiniRaman yeah sorry the question was confusing. the issue was that the lead had a unique ID field but that unique was not carried over to account or contact. so sometimes it would create duplicates on coversion. I ended up using the FindDuplicates Class to find the duplicates before conversion and attach to the lead.